# Can we have a better notification when a change is made to a favorite question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

When I add a question to favorites, the only notification is the blue flag on the profile page when there is activity on it. It is very easy to not see the change to a favorite question.

Can we get a better notification about changes in favorites questions?

Comment: What kind of alert did you want?

Comment: The blue colored label beside the favorites tab title is not enough. Let we say make its color flashing, or making it as inbox message. @bluefeet

Comment: An inbox notification would be nice

Comment: I could see an inbox notification getting to be noisy.  I'm not sure I see the benefit.

Comment: When someone add something to the favorites, the mention to something changed to them is not going to be noisy at all. The most reason to add a question to favorites is to observe an answer for it.

Comment: Well, if notification message may be regarded noisy, we may think in another way.

Comment: If you are really interested in your favorites, how hard is it to look at your profile once a day? Activity on a favorited question is not nearly the same level as importance as an answer or comment to my posts to me.

Comment: @sємsєм I made a few edits to your request to make this a bit clearer. It didn't seem like it was a `bug` report but a `feature-request`.  Feel free to rollback if I interpreted it wrong.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If your suppose is correct, so why they made achievement color in green while notification in other color red? It is the psychological effect of the color itself and its being as different than other.

Comment: @bluefeet Thank you very much for the edit.

Comment: *"The most reason to add a question to favorites is to observe an answer for it"* - that's not how I use them, for one!

Comment: Perhaps an option for a notification or similar would be nice- Some people use favorites to track questions that should be closed when they've run out of votes. I use it on Meta for questions that I'm interested in the answers to. I would want the notifications- People in the first class likely would not, and would not need it.

Comment: I'm not completely up to you regarding a feature-request involving a direct notification (my favorite tag's list is too big to appreciate this). I'd support some improvement to actually spot immediately, which of my favorite questions had recent actions without changing to the `activity` tab.

Comment: I know this has been asked for before (and was marked `status-declined`), but I can't seem to locate it now. I am not in favor of the idea of getting favorites notifications in my inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a good feature request for me.

A implemention could be to have an item in the inbox like we have on edits/answers. If someone clicks on this notification, I would like to be redirected to the new answer.

Since some people use the favorite list for canonical dup targets, and do not want to get notified, this feature should be optional. Maybe we could enable and disable it on our profile settings page.

Answer (score 5):

You can now "follow" individual questions and answers, which will provide you with an alert whenever the post is modified:

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices. You will not receive notifications for any action that you performed. As was mentioned in the earlier post, we are not making changes at this point to the notifications received by a post owner, or due to @mentions.

See details in the announcement on the global Meta site:
[The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network)