# Is there a simple way to get notifications on a post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, notifications

As the title says, is there a simple way to receive all the notifications regarding a particular post? The post, its answers or comments do not have to be mine. For example, there could be a bell icon near the `flag` option that could be toggled on and off.

Edit 1: Adding to favorites is a less favorable option as I explain below. That will clutter my favorite section.

Edit 2: So my question is almost similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13546/please-allow-me-to-follow-questions), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates)  and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you). Except that I propose a simple bell icon which can be toggled on and off. Since RSS feed seems to be the overwhelming choice (probably except [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1833/193365) answer), I am going to try it now.

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294136/can-we-have-a-better-notification-when-a-change-is-made-to-a-favorite-question - I missed it. Very confusing how well hidden favorites are.

Comment: No, I don’t want to add it to my favorites. I don’t value that question so much to add it to my favorites but just interested enough that I want to look at the answers, note down something and then forget about it. Adding everything to favorites will clutter that section.

Comment: That's fine, I only speculated it might be related - I wanted to get notification on changes on posts I do like. I still think this is a good idea, regardless. Maybe adding to "favorites" a "watching" page, and allowing an optional notification, or not.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[Please allow me to follow questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13546)*

Comment: [Each question has an RSS feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/376656) - search for "question feed" on any question page (including this one). Related (cross-site): *[RSS feed for questions which includes comments and / or edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254334)*. Firefox has a reasonable RSS reader (though not as awesome as [Opera's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29)) - but for some reason they try really hard to hide it away in Firefox - here is [some guidance on how to enable it](https://superuser.com/questions/261123).

Comment: The practical limit in Firefox for the built-in RSS reader is about 15 feeds (and that is after manually shortening the feed names) as the rest will be hidden under ">>" to the right. Whereas in Opera there is no limit as new items land in the same place, a sort of mail box (and there is no need to manually check each RSS feed for new items).

Comment: Note that Firefox is currently discontinuing their built-in RSS reader anyway.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The RSS feed for the question does not contain comments, right?

Comment: You can get question timeline via API: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/376656/timeline?site=meta.stackoverflow . Is there anyone desperate enough to write some notification tool or RSS wrapper on the top of it? :D

Comment: @PeterMortensen I totally didn't know about the question feed. I'd seen the link but I thought it was for the HNQ, since it's immediately after it. At any rate, is there an equivalent for specific *answers*?

Comment: The RSS reader in Firefox has now been disabled/effectively removed. An acceptable alternative is to use Mozilla Thunderbird (though the user interface for RSS feeds could be more intuitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now "follow" individual questions and answers, which will provide you with an alert whenever the post is modified:

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices. You will not receive notifications for any action that you performed. As was mentioned in the earlier post, we are not making changes at this point to the notifications received by a post owner, or due to @mentions.

See details in the announcement on the global Meta site:
[The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network)